# Using Google Api and I have imported Json and Requests to get an elevation of type int to display

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

```
import json,requests 

def elevation(lat,lon):
    apikey="MY_KEY"
    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json"
    response=requests.get(url+"?locations="+str(lat)+str(lon)+"&key="+apikey)
    data=response.json()

    print(data["results"][0]["elevation"])
```

`elevation(39.73915360,-104.98470340)`

**The Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\------\elevation.py", line 13, in <module>
    elevation(39.73915360,-104.98470340)
  File "c:\------\elevation.py", line 10, in elevation
    print(data["results"][0]["elevation"])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I figured this would be right. Data is of type dictionary so I believe that data["results"][0]["elevation"] would be correct. Not sure how it is out of range..I have tried with 2 different locations from the samples and they both have this error.

This is the example request for the google elevation api on there website

[image]

Comment: you have put `print(data["results"][0]["elevation"])` at `line 10` and `elevation(39.73915360,-104.98470340)` at `line 13`, how are you getting value in `data` outside your function?, you are not returning anything from your function `elevation`.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of variable "data" is limited inside the function. You should either do one of the following

````
**1) write print statement inside the function:**
import json,requests 

def elevation(lat,lon):
    apikey="MY_KEY"
    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json"
    response=requests.get(url+"?locations="+str(lat)+str(lon)+"&key="+apikey)
    data=response.json()
    print(data["results"][0]["elevation"])

elevation(39.73915360,-104.98470340)

                              **OR**
**2)return the value of data:**

import json,requests 

def elevation(lat,lon):
    apikey="MY_KEY"
    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json"
    response=requests.get(url+"?locations="+str(lat)+str(lon)+"&key="+apikey)
    data=response.json()
    return(data)

data = elevation(39.73915360,-104.98470340)
print(data["results"][0]["elevation"])```
````

Comment: Oh sorry. This is my first question here so I understanding how to copy code onto here. The code is now updated on the question, so I was doing it the way you showed and I still have gotten this error.

Comment: Please once print the value of "data" as well as "response" and check whether you get the proper output. I guess the response is blank so you are facing this issue as it could not find the 0th index from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Please once print the value of "data" as well as "response" and check whether you get the proper output. I guess the response is blank so you are facing this issue as it could not find the 0th index from the null data.